# why need to set client socket fd is non-blocked in server using select?

Tags: linux, sockets, select

Everyone,hello!
I have question about select model in practice.Some content of book tell me about set received socket fd to non-blocking in select model.I don't know cause.
As far as I'm concerned, I can know if client socket fd is readable by FD_ISSET(fd_all[i], fd_readable_set).So why I need set client socket fd to non-blocking?
Anyone tell my why?Thank you!

Comment: A completely useless question. 'Some book tell me'. What book? Tells you *exactly* what?

Comment: @EJP,sorry, I have a no clearly description. No "Some book", it is some data from web.for example:
http://www.cnblogs.com/zhuyp1015/archive/2012/05/31/2529203.html
https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000003063859

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes there's a change in the socket between the time that `select()` determines that it's readable and when your application actually tries to read from it. So it's safest to make it non-blocking so that you don't get hung when you try to read.

One possible way this can happen is if you have multiple processes or threads all calling `select()` on the same socket. When data arrives, they'll all return and try to read it, but only the first will succeed.

Comment: ,In multiple processes or threads, once select function return all processes or threas will receive some fd_set.Is that so?

Comment: Yes, if they're all waiting on the same FD that has become readable.